# Need an explanation for the dual maps in the book of Linear Algebra by Werner Greub

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

In the book of *Linear Algebra by Werner Greub* at page 68, there is an example, which is

> As an example of dual mappings consider the dual pairs $E^*$, $E$ and $E^* / E_1^\perp$, $E_1$, where $E_1$ is the subspace of E and let $\pi$ be the canonical projection of $E^*$ onto $E^* / E_1^\perp$. $$\pi :E^* \to E^* / E_1^\perp.$$ Then the canonical injection  $$i: E_1 \to E$$  is dual to $\pi$. In fact if $x\in E_1$, and $y^* \in E^*$ are arbitrary, we have  $$\langle y^*, i(x) \rangle = \langle y^*, x \rangle = \langle \bar y^*, x \rangle = \langle \pi y^*, x \rangle,$$ where $y^*$ is the representative of the class $\bar y^*$.

But I didn't get it how $\langle y^*, x \rangle = \langle \bar y^*, x \rangle$, so can someone explain to me this with more elementary concepts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Greub defines duality for a bilinear map $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : E^* \times E \to \Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is the underlying field and $E, E^*$ are $\Gamma$-vector spaces.

In this context, we let $E_1$ be a subspace of $E$ and let $E_1^\perp$ be the subspace of $E^*$ of all $y^* \in E^*$ such that $\langle y^*, x \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in E_1$. We then **define a bilinear function** $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : E^*/E_1^\perp \times E_1 \to \Gamma$ by

$$ \langle \bar y^*, x \rangle = \langle y^*, x \rangle$$
for some $y^* \in \bar y^*$. This is well defined because if $y_1^*, y_2^* \in \bar y^*$ are two representatives then (by definition) $y_2^* - y_1^* \in E_1^\perp$ and hence for all $x \in E_1$,

$$ \langle y_1^*, x \rangle = \langle y_1^*, x \rangle + \underbrace{\langle y_2^* - y_1^*, x \rangle}_0 = \langle y_2^*, x \rangle. $$

---

**Example**

Let $E = \operatorname{span}\{e_1, e_2\}$ and $E^* = \operatorname{span}\{e_1^*, e_2^*\}$. Define $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : E^* \times E \to \Gamma$ by

$$ \langle ae_1^* + be_2^*, ce_1 + de_2 \rangle = ac + bd. $$

Let $E_1 = \operatorname{span}\{e_1\}$. Then $E_1^\perp = \operatorname{span}\{e_2^*\}$ and we have the bilinear pair $E^*/E_1^\perp \times E_1 \to \Gamma$ given by

$$ \langle a\bar e_1^*, ce_1 \rangle = \langle ae_1^* + be_2^*, ce_1 \rangle = ac $$

where $a\bar e_1^* = \{ae_1^* + be_2^* : b \in \Gamma\}$. Notice that the element of this coset (the value of $b$) does not affect the bilinear map.

Comment: I didn't get it how you passed from LHS to RHS in this line, and why the second term is zero: $\langle y_1^*, x \rangle = \langle y_1^*, x \rangle + \underbrace{\langle y_2^* - y_1^*, x \rangle}_0$

Comment: Addition to that, can't we say that from the definition $\langle \bar y_1^*, x \rangle = \langle y^*, x \rangle = \langle \bar y_2^*, x \rangle$ since both $y_1^*$ and $y_2^*$ are in $\bar y^*$?

Comment: @Leth Let $w^* = y_2^* - y_1^*$. Then $w^* \in E_1^\perp$ and so by definition $\langle w^*, x \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in E_1$. Since this is $0$, I can add it to the left hand side. Indeed, you can say that and in fact, $\bar y_1^* = \bar y_2^*$ by definition. See Section 1.16 on page 28 in Greub's book to recall the definition of a factor space (a.k.a quotient space).

Comment: Ok got it, thank you so much.I really appreciated your effort to help me.